# Install Windows 8 Apps to custom directory

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8

I'm running Windows 8 Pro on a laptop. I initially installed the OS just to fiddle round with it and get to know something I'd inevitably end up having to fix for someone.

The problem being I only gave the partition about 32gb and that ran out pretty quick. I'd like to install office and get used to that as well but unfortunately I'm a few gigabytes short.

I'd like to know if I can change the install location of office 2013 and other apps so that I can run them from another partition because there is no space left to the right of this partition I can't extend it.

Comment: You could possibly get away with a mount point or something, worst case.

Comment: Sure, you can install Office 2013 to any location you want.

Comment: What is wrong with custom installation, or option about `Browse` to choose Installation directory?